# How do I access the parent siblings within a method?

Tags: jquery

How do I access the parent sibling?

I'm looking at these two:

```
elem.parent().siblings('#js-userLogged').val()
elem.parent().siblings('#js-eventId').val()

...= function()
{
    function addComment(elem, comment)
    {
        $.post('/shindig/ajax-add-comment', 
        {
            eventId : elem.parent().siblings('#js-eventId').val(), 
            userLogged : elem.parent().siblings('#js-userLogged').val(), 
            comment: comment, 
            ajax: true
        }, 
        function(data)
        {
            ...
```

HTML:

```
<div class="newComments">
    <input id="js-userLogged" type="hidden" value="111111111" name="userLogged"/>
    <input id="js-eventId" type="hidden" value="9999" name="eventId"/>
    <textarea class="addComment" value="Write a comment..." placeholder="Write a comment..." title="Write a comment..." ></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `elem`? is it one of the input/textarea fields

Comment: function addComment(elem, comment){
which is being called from Shindig.addComment($(this), comment);

Comment: ... yes its the textarea

Comment: Depending on what you're expecting `.siblings('#js-eventId')` to find, it may not support what you have in mind. `id`s should only be used once throughout the `<html>` document and so jQuery will stop looking after the 1st.

Comment: Im expecting to find each of the input field within its parent. div. newComments is one of many fields.

For example, I needed to display the comment field for each element set, and did this without a unique idea by working the DOM like so:

 $(".js-event-comment").click(function(){
   $(this).parents(".event-info").siblings(".comments").slideToggle("fast");
  });

I was looking to do the same thing, but I dont know how to do this within the a function without passing each field value at the point of calling the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `elem` is the textarea then the input fields are its siblings, not the parent elements. so try

```
$.post('/shindig/ajax-add-comment', {
    eventId: elem.siblings('#js-eventId').val(),
    userLogged: elem.siblings('#js-userLogged').val(),
    comment: comment,
    ajax: true
}, function (data) {})
```

Also note that the id of elements must be unique, so if you have multiple structures like this in your page then it will be better to use a class/name attribute to find the element like

```
$.post('/shindig/ajax-add-comment', {
    eventId: elem.siblings('[name="eventId"]').val(),
    userLogged: elem.siblings('[name="userLogged"]').val(),
    comment: comment,
    ajax: true
}, function (data) {})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as Stack allows me.